# Clips 6.4 not generating initial-fact?

Tags: clips, expert-system

I'm testing if CLIPS generates the initial-fact after a (reset) command with CLIPSIDE 6.4. But it don't generates it.
It's dissapeared this initial-fact in the last versions?

Screenshot of clips (reset) and (facts) output:
[image: screenshot of clips (reset) and (facts) output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `initial-fact` and `initial-object` were removed in CLIPS 6.40 as noted in the Update Release Notes of the [Reference Manual](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v640/bpg.pdf).

> - Initial Fact – The initial-fact deftemplate and deffacts are no longer supported.
> - Initial Object  –   The   INITIAL-OBJECT   defclass   and   initial-object   definstances   are   nolonger supported.